# A-Frame I can't detect the marker in javascript

Tags: three.js, augmented-reality, aframe, ar.js

Hello I would like to run an alert when a market is detected, but i can't get any working example, the strange think is that i have this error when i put the image in front of the camera, it's mean that the detection works but the addEventListener doesn't

[image]

if you want to try this is the glitch code
https://glitch.com/edit/#!/fresh-handsomely-innocent

and the marker to detect is the default [one on this site](https://jeromeetienne.github.io/AR.js/three.js/examples/marker-training/examples/generator.html)

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/three.js/0.156.1/three.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://aframe.io/releases/1.2.0/aframe.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/jeromeetienne/AR.js/2.0.0/aframe/build/aframe-ar.js"></script>

    <script>
      AFRAME.registerComponent('marker-handler', {
        init: function () {
          var marker = this.el;

          marker.addEventListener('markerFound', function (event) {
            var markerId = event.target.id;
            alert('Marker Found: ' + markerId);

            var text = marker.querySelector('a-text');
            text.setAttribute('visible', 'true');
          });
        }
      });
    </script>
  </head>
  
  <body style="margin: 0; overflow: hidden;">
    <a-scene embedded arjs>
      <!-- Light -->
      <a-light type="ambient" position="0 5 0" intensity="0.5"></a-light>
      <a-light type="directional" position="2 4 -3" intensity="0.8"></a-light>

      <!-- Model to load -->
      <a-assets>
        <a-asset-item id="dinosauro" src="https://cdn.glitch.global/9f3550c1-a3d9-466b-bf74-58c85d1a9ee0/tyrannosarus_rex_free_model.glb?v=1694031316403"></a-asset-item>
      </a-assets>    
      
      <a-marker-camera type="pattern" url="https://cdn.glitch.global/9f3550c1-a3d9-466b-bf74-58c85d1a9ee0/pattern-marker.patt?v=1694025287942">
        <a-entity marker-handler gltf-model="#dinosauro" position="0 -0.5 -4.4" scale="0.1 0.1 -0.1" rotation="0 45 0" visible="false"></a-entity>
        <a-text marker-handler value="Hello, AR!" position="0 0 -3.5" color="red" align="center" visible="false"></a-text>
      </a-marker-camera>
    </a-scene>
  </body>
</html>
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)